# отступы в цикле JS

Tags: javascript

Практикуюсь на таблице умножения:

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  let result = '';
  for (j = 2; j <= 10; j++) {
    (result += (i * j)) <= 9 ? result += '  ' : result += ' ';
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

Результаты вроде корректные.
Проблема с отступами, тернарным оператором пробую сделать если число однозначное(<= 9) то добавлять 2 пробела после числа, если нет, то один пробел, но так почему то в консоли действует только для первой колонки, для последующих присваивается один пробел, ЧЯДНТ? Есть может замечания по коду и более изящные варианты исполнения таблицы умножения?

Comment: Надеюсь из ответа станет понятно что вы делали не так, но если всёже нет то вы сравнивали `<= 9` с вот этим `2  3`

Comment: не совсем понял, сравниваю с 2 3??

Comment: После подсчета первого столбика `result=2` после второго `result=2  3` т.е. там уже не одиночное число, а два числа через пробел, и вы эти два числа через пробел проверяете на размер (`'2  3'<=9` `'2  3 4' <= 9`)

Comment: Теперь понятно, спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  let result = '';
  let temp = 0;
  for (j = 2; j <= 10; j++) {
    ((temp = (i * j)) <= 9) ? result += temp + '  ': result += temp + ' ';
  }
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: @Igor, к вам вопрос, как вы так код форматируете? и для каких ЯП это доступно?

Comment: В редакторе ответа - кнопка "Фрагмент кода" в тулбаре. Для js/html/css.